# QImage and transparency

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem when loading a PNG image, using Qt and especially the QImage class.

Actually, although the image contains transparent areas, my code doesn't detect transparent pixels of this image (according to the results I get, it is fully opaque, whereas it is not the case).

First, I read some questions related to this topic on Stack Overflow, and I tried a couple of stuffs, for example expliciting image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32) when I load the image, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me ? I think that I need a second pair of eyes on my code...

```cpp
void ImageManager::detectTransparentPixels() {

    QImage image("imqage.png");

    image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);

    int opaque = 0;

    int transparent = 0;

    for (int x = 0 ; x < width ; x++) {

        for (int y = 0 ; y < height ; y++) {

            QRgb currentPixel = (image.pixel(x, y));

            if (qAlpha(currentPixel) == 0) {

                transparent++;

            } else {

                opaque++;

            }

        }

    }

    std::cout << "Opaque pixels : " << opaque << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Transparent pixels : " << transparent << std::endl;
```

}

Thank you in advance and have a nice day...

Comment: This code works properly for me. Im on Qt5 + vs2010. Make sure your image is loaded properly. You have named it 'imqage.png', is this typo? And make sure the image has fully transparent pixels.

Comment: You can use the [`QImage::load`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#load) function to see if the image was loaded properly. *Returns true if the image was successfully loaded; otherwise invalidates the image and returns false.*

Comment: I see you're testing qAlpha == 0. Are you sure your transparent pixels are 100% transparent? Perhaps they're only 80% transparent, for instance, they'll get skipped by your test.

Comment: I agree with RobbieE's comment. Change your transparency test to: `(qAlpha(currentPixel) < 128)`